# How to debug a function in Python that only sometimes doesn't work?

Tags: python, numpy

I am going nuts because sometimes a function gives back the wrong pair of data! I have a numpy array with around 700 points:

```
np.array =[[  1.00000000e+01  -4.65000000e+02]
           [  1.78319153e+01  -4.60252579e+02]
          ...]
```

And I have a given point:

```
point [32.121456577748098, -241.01907826915999]
```

and just want to check where in my array is the point or index which is closest to my given point.

I use this line to find the nearest point:

```
 array[spatial.KDTree(array).query(point)[1]]
```

Which works nice. But sometimes it does not work! It just gives back an item from my array which is NOT closest.
Interesting fact is that when I try similar functions or solutions that both functions are not working at the same time. I have no idea why it works and sometimes not. The array and points are newly generated in a main loop that also used TCP and UDP. How can I in general debug it?

Thanks!

Comment: You have to assume the `query()` method works, else other users would have raised bug reports against numpy.

Comment: Perhaps you have multiple arrays and are searching the wrong array?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do this in numpy?

```
distance = np.sum((yourlist - yourpoint)**2.)**(1/2.)
index = np.argmin(distance)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not a direct answer to your specific question, but I would suggest that you simply compute `numpy.linalg.norm(data - point, axis=1)` and then use `numpy.argmin()` to find the index of the minimum norm.

Essentially:

```
dist = numpy.linalg.norm(data - point, axis=1)
minindex = np.argmin(dist)
closest_pt = data[minindex]
```